# Max number of gifts

Tags: pokemon-go

I currently have 10 gifts in my inventory and even after spinning 20+ Pokestops i didn't get any more!

So I was wondering: Is there a max number of gifts I can have in my inventory?

Comment: I didn't find an answer on gaming.stackexchange, but if there is, feel free to flag this as duplicate!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is a limit to how many gifts you can hold in your inventory. Once you have reached this limit, you cannot obtain any more gifts until you send them to your friends.

[Niantic Support](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001509908-Sending-and-Receiving-Gifts)

> You can hold a maximum of 10 Gifts in your Bag at any given time.